# Why do cricket and baseball each use the term 'pitch' but in different senses?

Tags: word-choice, sports

I should say from the outset that I do know the answer to this question, because I have just researched it. But it is so interesting that I felt it was worth an airing.

I am not clear if it is 'off-topic' to ask a question to which one knows the answer, but if it is I have no doubt whatever that someone will say so.

In baseball a 'pitcher' throws a very similar ball to a cricket ball directly at the batsman (if that is what he is called). The ball does not strike the ground first. Yet he 'pitches'.

In cricket a bowler delivers a ball at a wicket by first making it strike the ground somewhere in front of the batsman. (It doesn't have to strike the ground. If it hits the wicket without doing so the batsman is said to have been 'yorked').

But 'pitching' refers to the ball striking the ground (the pitch). We talk about short-pitched and long-pitched deliveries, of balls that pitch on the leg stump, or outside the offstump etc.

It long puzzled me why the person delivering a baseball was called a 'pitcher', because the ball does not 'pitch'. But now I know the answer. Does anyone else?

Edit. I should add that the word is also used in golf, with the same meaning that it has in cricket.

Comment: It's perfectly in order to answer your own question if you know the answer: it's even encouraged. But you do need to tick a checkbox on the Ask Question page to open the answer box.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I'll leave it there overnight to see if any of the Americans come up with the answer.

Comment: Doesn't _pitch_ mean "to throw" (as in _pitch horseshoes_, or _pitch that can of beer this way_)? I don't understand why it makes any difference whether the ball strikes the ground or not.

Comment: @J.R. Because in cricket if it doesn't strike the ground it doesn't 'pitch'. Where did the ball pitch? It pitched just outside the off stump. i.e. that is where it hit the ground. Or in golf: 'the ball "pitched" on the green, just three feet from the hole'.

Comment: Isn't it where WAS the ball pitched i.e. thrown, rather than where DID the ball pitch. Then short-pitched ball is a ball thrown short of a length (to use another cricketing term) or it was pitched outside the off stump, as in it was thrown so that it struck and bounced off the wicket outside of the line of the off stump. Also, a Yorker is a ball which bounces near to the batsman's feet, not one which hits the wicket without first bouncing. The latter would be a type of 'full toss', which refers to any delivery which reaches the batsman without bouncing.

Comment: @paulkayuk Sometimes a commentator will say 'It (meaning the ball) pitched near the batsman's feet', but occasionally, 'The bowler is pitching them short'. The ball or the bowler can be the subject of the verb. But if it is the ball, then 'pitch' is intransitive. Whichever way, 'pitching' refers to the ball hitting the ground. You are right about a 'yorker'. Strictly it is a ball that pitches either on the batsman's feet, or beyond, but also I believe at the base of the wicket; as opposed to a 'full-toss' which does not touch the ground at all before hitting the wicket.

Comment: @WS2 I would hold that the intransitive use of pitch when referring to the ball, though in common usage, is a more recent meaning and that pitch meaning thrown dates from the original game when the ball was thrown or pitched underarm.  Indeed, as cited in Oldcats answer, the ball was originally thrown underarm, or pitched, in baseball.

Comment: @paulkayuk This is an example from the laws of cricket, dated 1816   *W. Lambert Instr. & Rules Cricket 32   If a Ball should pitch short of its proper length on the off side, and should twist toward the top of the wicket, the Striker must be very careful in playing back that he does not hit his own wicket.* Meaning 12a from the OED shows that as well as meaning 'throw' (sense 13) 'pitch' also means to crash to the ground or fall heavily, with examples from the 14th century.

Comment: @WS2 nice find, how did that one pitch up? I sit corrected, with so many long standing meanings, pitch is definitely a 'utility word'.

Comment: @paulkayuk Acknowledgement will be gratefully received in the form of votes!

Comment: I was going to ask a question about why Americans say "pitch" when they want to throw away something: [*If it smells sharp, then pitch it. If it doesn't smell, cook it and try a little piece. If it has a "mealy" mouth-feel to it, or it smells or tastes sharp after cooking, pitch it.*](http://ask.metafilter.com/9567/Expired-Chicken) I guessed it had to be connected to baseball and a pitcher who pitches the ball, but why is it used when someone throws sth in the bin? Your questions and answer citing OED's "pitch fork" have answered that small query of mine. I wish I could upvote both again!

Comment: @Mari-LouA You are very kind. The word 'pitch' meaning 'throw' was used in England as early as the 14th century, well before either America or baseball was invented. But it is that sense of 'pitch' which is used in baseball. But the sense of 'pitch' used in both cricket and golf is a different one.

Answer (score 5):

Unlike now, baseball pitchers were originally required to deliver the ball *underhand*. This **pitching**, is an arcing underhand throw like a pitching wedge in golf.  The overhand, throwing motion is defined as an antonym in the original Knickerbocker rules in 1839.

> 9th. The ball must be pitched, not thrown, for the bat.
>
> The ball had to be literally "pitched," like a horseshoe. Overhand pitching in baseball was not allowed until 1884, although the progression from underhand to overhand was gradual, and pitchers stretched the limits of the rule by increasing speed and developing movement from the underhand position.

[WIKI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knickerbocker_Rules)-Knickerbocker Rules

Eventually the pitcher was allowed to deliver the ball overhand, but by then the pitcher name was firmly attached.

Comment: _Knockerbocker rules_ sounds like something your mum would make up to justify why you could only have sundae ice creams on the weekend…

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Sure it's not *knickerbockers' rule*?

Comment: @WS2 Ahem. Yes, _knickerbocker_. Butterfingers.

Comment: It was the Knickerbocker Club's Rules for Baseball. I only pulled out one rule, the ninth.

Answer (score 3):

People will by now perhaps have gathered that 'pitch' has two meanings (among many).

Baseball is employing sense 13 in the OED; which basically means to 'throw'. It has examples dating from the 14th century. 'Pitching hay' means 'throwing hay', and that is why a 'pitch fork' is used.

The word 'pitch' as used in cricket or golf is based on meaning 12a, also with examples from the 14th century, meaning to 'crash to the ground', or 'strike the ground'. OED meaning 12b refers specifically to sport, with references to the laws of cricket from 1816.

In cricket and golf 'pitch' is describing something the ball does, whilst in baseball it is something the 'thrower' does.

Very often, if a bowler (in cricket) is bowling 'short', someone will shout 'pitch-em up a bit'. Short-pitching is an important issue in cricket since it is used to intimidate the batsman as it causes the ball (travelling at anything up to 90mph) to come up around his head. Just a couple of weeks ago the young Australian batsman, Phil Hughes, was tragically killed when a ball (short-pitched) came up and struck him on the back of the neck, beneath his helmet, causing an artery to rupture.

Metaphors such as 'he pitched up for the meeting' follow the cricket or golf meaning.

Comment: In the rules I found, the meaning is even more specific. **Pitch** is to deliver the ball underhand, **throw** is to deliver it overhand.

Comment: @Oldcat So strictly speaking a modern baseball 'pitcher' should be called a 'thrower'. Is that what you are saying?

Comment: Well, he is *allowed* to throw underhand. Every so often a pitcher comes along with a submarine delivery.

Answer (score 1):

Related to pitchers originally pitching under, but now throwing over but retaining the term.. In cricket, the ball was originally bowled, like in bowls. Pitching the ball (bouncing it) came in when bowlers experimented with spinning the ball to make it behave less predictably.

Over time, the term stuck but overhand bowling became the norm, so much so that an international incident threatened to ensue when an Australian bowler bowled under-arm against New Zealand in 1981*. The rules were later amended to formally restrict bowling to above the waist.

It's known simply as the 'underarm incident' and can be watched on YouTube if you are so inclined.

Comment: And in that sense of *pitching* it meant the ball striking the ground. Terms like 'he pitched it well'. or 'he pitched it short' refer not to the action of the bowler, but where he managed to get the ball to strike the ground.